# Insertar en un input el nombre de la página desde la que se viene

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

¿Cómo puedo cargar un `input` deshabilitado desde una página anterior?

Me explico: Si abro la página que contiene el `input` desde la página `inicio`, quiero que el `input` tenga de texto *Vienes desde la página de inicio*, y si abro la página que contiene el `input` desde la página de imágenes, el `input` debe tener de texto *Vienes de la página de imágenes*.

**Página uno:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Página principal</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="pagina-visora.html">Click aquí para saber de dónde vienes</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Página 2:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Página 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="pagina-visora.html">Click aquí para saber de dónde vienes</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Página visora:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pagina visora</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" disabled="" name="visora" id="visora" value="Vienes de la página...">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: la primera que se me ocurre seria usar localstorage. Otra alternativa seria via parametros de la url donde por ejemplo des clic desde pagina1 y esta te mande a pagina2.html con los parametros de donde viene por ejemplo algo asi: `pagina2.html?pagina=pagina1` y con javascript obtener el valor de pagina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando la propiedad [Document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) puedes obtener la URL de la página desde la que vienes. Se me ocurre que mediante una expresión regular analices la URL `referrer` para extraer el texto que debes poner en cada caso:

> **Nota:** Dependiendo de cómo luzcan las URL de tus páginas debes cambiar la expresión regular para que coincida con las mismas:

Imaginemos que las URL de tus páginas son:

- https://misitio.com/inicio.html
- https://misitio.com/imagenes.html
- https://misitio.com/contacto.html

La expresión regular te debería devolver las siguientes cadenas tomando en cuenta esas URL:

```js
const reg = /\w+:\/\/[\w\.]+\/(\w+).\w{3,4}/;

const URL = [
  'https://misitio.com/inicio.html',
  'https://misitio.com/imagenes.html',
  'https://misitio.com/contacto.html'
];

const paginas = URL.map(url => url.replace(reg, '$1'));

console.log(paginas);
```

En la página que contiene el `input`, el código `JavaScript` que captura la URL `referrer` y la convierte en cadena, podría ser algo así:

> **Nota:** Debes saber que el siguiente snippet no funcionará aquí en StackOverflow, ya que como aclara la documentación: *Dentro de un `<iframe>`, el `Document.referrer` será inicializado con el valor de `href` de la `window.location` del documento padre.*

```js
const input = document.getElementById('referrer');
const reg = /\w+:\/\/[\w\.]+\/(\w+).\w{3,4}/;

input.value = document.referrer
  ? `Vienes de la página ${document.referrer.replace(reg, '$1')}`
  : 'Has visitado la página directamente';
```

```css
#referrer {
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<input id="referrer" />
```